Exclude Targets from package using Swift Package Manager on Swift
I am trying to use two Packages, Paypal and Brain Tree, those packages have three similar targets bc both have Paypal frameworks, when I use both I receive "Multiple Targets named 'PPRiskMagnes', 'PaypalCheckout', I want to exclude those targets from Brain Tree, It is possible to configure in the Package File?
